# Angular routing problem. App.component content shows in every component

Tags: angular, routes

I have problem with showing app.component content on every component.
This is my app.component code:

[image]

I don't want to share navbar and app-users to other components, but this content shows in every other components. Thank you for any help!

Comment: AppComponent is the root component and is always rendered, you will have to move this to another component if you don't want it shown on every page. Also: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App routing is rendering besides navbar and users component then these two components will be rendered in any of the app routes. I suggest you make another component consisting navbar and users and add this to the application routing.
`new.component.html` will look like this:

```
 <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <!-- other elemets --> 
 <app-users></app-users>
```

The `app.component.html` will look like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do that you should change your folder structure in your project and do like that :
first: you should create home component and place the  inside of the home component .
second : in your app component you should write these codes :

```
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <app-home></app-home>
  <app-user></app-user>
```

based on these structure, navbar and user just in one component and home always changes based on the route config.

I hope it works for you

Comment: this is unreadable